# Trying to run a .net Core HelloWorld console app on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have created a simple console app in .net Core 2.1 and compiled the following output:

```
HelloWorld.deps.json 
HelloWorld.dll 
HelloWorld.pdb 
HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.dev.json 
HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.json
```

I have installed the .net Core SDK (link here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-current)

```
    user1@VMLinuxTest:~/Downloads/bin$ dotnet run HelloWorld.dll

    Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in /home/user1/Downloads/bin, 
    or pass the path to the project using --project.
```

I'm simply trying to run the console app using the `dotnet run` command.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21):

> The dotnet run command is used in the context of projects, not built assemblies. If you're trying to run a framework-dependent application DLL instead, you must use dotnet without a command. For example, to run myapp.dll, use:

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

The `dotnet run` command is only used when you reference .csproj files

Comment: That was it!  Doh!  Thanks very much!